# Adding comma(,) or "or" in depending on position in between conditional text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am having 5 products Product P, Q R, S, T input XML will differ some time one or two or three or four or five products may present but here 5 products XML posted some times products may repeat like product Q two times and product R three times and some products may miss

```
<products>
<product>Product_P</product>
<product>Product_Q</product>
<product>Product_R</product>
<product>Product_S</product>
<product>Product_T</product>
</products>
```

if input xml 2 products repeated:

```
<products>
    <product>Product_P</product>
    <product>Product_Q</product>
    <product>Product_R</product>
<product>Product_Q</product>
    <product>Product_R</product>
    <product>Product_S</product>
<product>Product_Q</product>
    <product>Product_R</product>
    <product>Product_T</product>
    </products>
```

if input xml 3 missing some products:

```
<products>
    <product>Product_P</product>
    <product>Product_Q</product>
    <product>Product_T</product>
    </products>
```

if input xml 4 other type products:

```
<products>
    <product>Product_P</product>
    <product>Product_U</product>
    <product>Product_R</product>
<product>Product_V</product>
    <product>Product_R</product>
    <product>Product_W</product>
<product>Product_Q</product>
    <product>Product_W</product>
    <product>Product_T</product>
    </products>
```

I need the output products related to P, Q, R, S,T no other products As mentioned below:

if input has one product that value equal to product="Product_Q", i want to Simply print

```
Product_Q
```

if input has two products value equal to product="Product_Q" and product="Product_S", i want to print

```
Product_Q or Product_S
```

if input has three products value equal to product="Product_P", product="Product_Q" and product="Product_R", i want to print

```
Product_P, Product_Q or Product_R
```

if input has four products values equal to product="Product_P", product="Product_Q",  product="Product_R" and product="Product_T", i want to print

```
Product_P, Product_Q, Product_R, Product_S or Product_T
```

if input has five products values equal to product="Product_P", product="Product_Q",  product="Product_R", product="Product_S" and product="Product_T", i want to print

```
Product_P, Product_Q, Product_R, Product_S  or Product_T
```

I have tried the below XSLT template

```
<xsl:template match="products">
           <xsl:variable name="product" select="products/product"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$product='Product_P'">
                        <xsl:text>Product_P</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$product='Product_P' and Product_Q">
                        <xsl:text>or</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$product='Product_Q'">
                        <xsl:text>Product_Q</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$product='Product_P' and Product_Q and Product_R">
                        <xsl:text>or</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$product='Product_R'">
                        <xsl:text>Product_R</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$product='Product_S'">
                        <xsl:text>Product_S</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$product='Product_T'">
                        <xsl:text>Product_T</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Please assist
thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. When you say there are 5 products, do you mean that there will always be some subset of these 5 products? Perhaps it would help to explain how the output of your stylesheet differs from your required output.

Comment: The input XML will differ,  depending on the input XML only products text will display, if five products in a XML output should be Product_P, Product_Q, Product_R, Product_S or Product_T

Comment: You're having real trouble articulating your requirements, so I suggest you give us three or four example inputs and the corresponding outputs.

Comment: Hi @Michael Kay I have added 4 types of XML fourth one having different type of products other than P, Q, R, S, T. I need the output products related to P, Q, R, S,T no other products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to identify the distinct products:

```
distinct-values(products/product)
```

then filter the result with a predicate that selects the products you want to retain:

```
[matches(., '^Product_[PQRST]$')]
```

then add the formatting:

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(products/product)[matches(., '^Product_[PQRST]$')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="if (position()=1) then ''
                        else if (position()=last()) then ' or '
                        else ', '"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note: your requirements still say nothing about the required order of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template name="ListProducts">
    <xsl:param name="products" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count($products) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$products"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="count($products) = 2">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($products[1], ' or ', $products[2])"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- output first product and recursively call with remainder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($products[1], ', ')"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="ListProducts">
          <xsl:with-param name="products" select="$products[position() > 1]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="ListProducts">
        <xsl:with-param name="products" select="product" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output when run on your sample XML:

```
<products>Product_P, Product_Q, Product_R, Product_S or Product_T</products>
```

Comment: Thank you @JLRishe , It's helpful the required output is same but in my XML products are repeated I am adding another input XML in the question

Comment: @User515 It doesn't look like you added another input XML to the question.

Comment: I have added 4 types of XML fourth one having different type of products other than P, Q, R, S, T. I need the output products related to P, Q, R, S,T no other products